# Programa em Python 3

Tags: python

Sou iniciante em Python 3. Estou utilizando o **PyCharm v.2017.3.3** e gostaria de saber como finalizar o meu projeto **"Hello World"** para um amigo rodar em seu Windows. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Grato.

Comment: Não posso te dizer o que é melhor, mas uma ferramenta que usei com sucesso no passado foi cx_freeze. Eles atualizaram recentemente (em 7 de janeiro de 17) para a versão 5.0.1 e suporta o Python 3.6. Aqui está o pypi https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze Docs mostram que há mais de uma maneira de fazê-lo dependendo de suas necessidades.
http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html

Comment: Sou novo no stackoverflow.